# Duda con PostBack y evento SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Primero que nada, les pido perdón porque no puedo presentar código. El problema es el siguiente en una aplicacion asp.net webforms, tengo 2 listbox y cada uno tiene el evento de SelectedIndexChanged, (el código dentro de esos eventos es simplemente mover un item de una lista a la otra y viceversa) los cuales se manejan cuando hay PostBack y cuando algún elemento está seleccionado. Tengo 1 simple boton con el evento de click pero sin código, digamos que simplemente sirve para hacer PostBack. Ahora, el problema surge porque tengo otro botón el cual activa otro evento pero si yo tengo algun item seleccionado de alguna de las listbox, lo que se ejecuta es primero el evento de SelectedIndexChanged y luego el evento al que llama el segundo botón y en realidad solo quiero que se ejecute el evento del segundo botón, me explico? Cómo podría evitar esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en esta imagen de ejemplo, si yo doy click en el botón de Save, al tener seleccionado un item del listbox de la izquierda, lo que hace la aplicación es llamar al evento SelectedIndexChanged de ese listbox y recién luego de eso llama al evento de Save, y esto funciona asi por la cuestión del PostBack. Hay alguna buena forma para implementar que evite eso?

Comment: Casi todo el comportamiento que describes se puede desarrollar del lado del cliente (con javascript) sin que haya un postback. El resto de funcionalidad, la que requiera código del lado del servidor, la puedes invocar con Ajax.

Comment: Por lo que vi revisando en internet, muchos recomiendan lo que mencionaste. Pensé que tal vez podría haber alguna forma desde el mismo asp y webform.

Comment: Si existe forma, pero si lo que quieres es evitar un postback, lo mejor es trabajar lo que más se pueda desde el lado del cliente.

Comment: Me podrías comentar como sería la idea de esa forma de resolver desde el mismo asp?

Comment: Bueno, ponerte aqui todo el ejemplo es un poco largo, pero puedes revisar este fiddle que muestra algo parecido a lo que tu quieres haciendo uso de Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/rTxb8/ (Aclaro que el Fiddle no es mio, lo tomé de: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719768/trying-to-move-one-option-to-another-select-list) Espero te sirva.

Comment: Yo lo que haría sería en lugar de implementar la lógica en el SelectedIndexChanged implementarla en los clicks de los botones, me parece consistente. (por otro lado pedi un a revisión para sacar el label de ASP.NET pero fue un error mio, el tag está bien)

Comment: kblok, vos decís de mover la logica al evento de Click en esos botones para mover entre listbox (>> y <<)? Pero haciendo esto no sabría si es muy conveniente con el código actualmente, ya que podría tener referencias a ese evento en muchas partes del proyecto de las cuales no tengo idea, no obstante sería una solución viable si no tuviese problemas con esas referencias.

Comment: Sin el código es bastante difícil adivinar en donde se encuentra la falla. Sugiero que pongas segmentos de código, si tiene información sensible cámbiala por datos *dumny*, además de que la forma en que hayas programado esta funcionalidad es la responsable del comportamiento inesperado. Aún con la recompensa no me animaría a responder bajo especulaciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrías hacer uso del control UpdatePanel de las extensiones Ajax (el cual ya está pre-instalado en Visual Studio), y son utilizados para hacer postback solo en la porción de la pagina que encierran, acomoda tus ListBox y UpdatePanel algo así:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:ListBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ListBox2" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <br />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Item 3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item 4</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:ListBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ListBox1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Ahora te explico:

- El ScriptManager es requisito para utilizar los UpdatePanel.
- Nota que estos tienen la propiedad UpdateMode="Conditional" que sirve para condicionar que eventos van a disparar el postback dentro de ellos.
- Pon la propiedad AutoPostBack="True" en los ListBox ya que por default esta en false y es necesaria para enviar datos al servidor y obtener la respuesta.
- Las etiquetas "Triggers" y "asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger" las puse para determinar que evento va a disparar la actualización del UpdatePanel. (los controles con autopostback dentro de su UpdatePanel dispararan el evento por si mismo sin necesidad de identificarlo en la etiqueta Triggers) Y porque para actualizar el ViewState es necesario hacer postback, así que ambos ListBox dependen de uno y el otro para cambiar su vista. Adaptalo a tu código ASP y cuentame si te funciono. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el código no lo estás poniendo en el controlador de eventos correcto.

Tal y como explicas, estás poniendo código en el evento SelectedIndexChanged del ListBox que quieres que se ejecute cuando haces click en un determinado botón si hay un elemento seleccionado en el ListBox.

Si quieres que se ejecute el código cuando se hace click en un determinado botón lo lógico es que dicho código se encuentre en el controlador del evento click del botón.

Si, por el contrario, quisieras tener un código que se ejecutara cada vez que el usuario seleccione una opción diferente en el ListBox, lo que deberías hacer es poner la propiedad AutoPostBack del ListBox a true y utilizar el evento SelectedIndexChanged de éste.

Entiendo que en tu caso nos encontramos en el primer escenario. Por lo tanto deberías eliminar el controlador del evento SelectedIndexChanged e incluir el código en el controlador del evento Click del botón realizando la comprobación de que hay algún elemento seleccionado en el ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

Estamos en este escenario:

- 2 Listbox con su propio SelectedIndexChanged y el evento PostBack activo
- 1 botón que realiza otra cosa con PostBack activo

Al pulsar en el botón se ejecuta el método SelectedIndexChanged y después el del propio botón.

---

Comprueba:

- Que los dos ListBox tienen el PostBack activo
- Que el evento OnLoad no llama a alguno de los eventos SelectedIndexChanged
- Que el evento OnClick del botón no llama por error a uno de los métodos SelectedIndexChanged de los listbox

Answer (score 0):

---

> Popplar : Ahora, el problema surge porque tengo otro botón el cual
>   activa otro evento pero si yo tengo algun item seleccionado de alguna
>   de las listbox, lo que se ejecuta es primero el evento de
>   SelectedIndexChanged y luego el evento al que llama el segundo botón y
>   en realidad solo quiero que se ejecute el evento del segundo botón, me
>   explico? Cómo podría evitar esto?

---

Fíjate si en el evento Page_Load se está llamando al evento SelectedIndexChanged  o a algún método que esté moviendo el item seleccioando a la otra lista.

Tras el post-back, primero se ejecuta el Page_Load y luego el evento del botón (ej Boton_Click ).

Espero te sirva!